# CRITICAL_SECTION / CONDITION_VARIABLE Deadlock in Win32

Tags: multithreading, winapi

Why does this code cause a deadlock?

THREAD 1:

```
EnterCriticalSection( &lock_ );

... Create thread 1

EnterCriticalSection( &lock_ );
while (pred) {
    SleepConditionVariableCs( &cond_, &lock_ );
    // At this point, I would expect thread #2 to wake up, but it doesn't.
}
LeaveCriticalSection( &lock_ );
LeaveCriticalSEction( &lock_ );
```

THREAD 2:

```
EnterCriticalSection( &lock_ );

// This never runs
... Do something else for a while

LeaveCriticalSection( &lock_ );
```

According to the Win32 API, EnterCriticalSection can be called twice in a row from the same thread without deadlocking.  It appears that SleepConditionVariableCS only unlocks the critical section once, which means that thread #2 will never run.  Is my reasoning correct here?

Basically, what I want is something like Java's ReentrantLock.  What's the difference between ReentrantLock and CRITICAL_SECTION?

Comment: Correct. `SleepConditionVariableCs` exits the critical section only once. It is also correct that `EnterCriticalSection` can be called twice in a row from the same thread without deadlocking. But if you plan to call `SleepConditionVariableCs`, you must exit the critical section all but once (i.e., the enter count must be exactly 1 at the point you call `SleepConditionVariableCs`). In the above example, it means calling `LeaveCriticalSection` immediately before the `SleepConditionVariableCs` and `EnterCriticalSection` immediately after.

Comment: Raymond, if you wrote this as an answer rather than a comment I would have accepted it :)

Comment: Go ahead and write your own answer and accept it.

Comment: Or simply don't call `EnterCriticalSection()` twice before calling `SleepConditionVariableCs()` to begin with, then you don't need to call `LeaveCriticalSection()` before calling `SleepConditionVariableCs()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that SleepConditionVariableCS only unlocks the critical section once, which means that thread #2 will never run.